# Repeating the process : displaying a view for an random time then make it invisible for an random time

Tags: android, handler, visibility

The title says it all. I want to make a view into an infinite loop of random visibility and invisibility. This is how I approached it :-

First I created two methods to get Random time getRandomWaitTime() and getRandomDisplayTime(). These methods are well defined and tested (in Log) and are working as desired. Both these methods return a random value as int in millisecond as

```
getRandomWaitTime()     :   3000-6000
getRandomDisplayTime()  :   3000-5000
```

Now I created one ImageView fruit[0], set it initially as invisible and after that the following code is executed :

```
fruit[0].postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fruit[0].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fruit[0].postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        fruit[0].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }, getRandomDisplayTime());
                fruit[0].postDelayed(this, getRandomWaitTime());
                }
        }, getRandomWaitTime());
```

The code compiles, executes as well, the ImageView goes through infinite cycle of visibility and invisibility **but the time for which it is set as visible or invisible doesn't seem to have minimum value of 3000ms** Sometimes it feels like it is visible for a 500ms and then gone invisible. I have tried a ton of things such as using Handler.postDelayed instead of View.postDelayed but this doesn't seem to work.

Interesting thing happens when I remove all `getRandomWaitTime()` and `getRandomDisplayTime()` methods from postDelayed method and replace then with a constant like 3000.

The activity starts. At first fruit[0] is set to invisible. After 3000ms it comes visible and **stays there**. Nothing happens after it. No more switching to invisibility. I just stays there.

So what could be the possible reasons for all these sorcery problems?

Comment: `fruit[0]` is a type of `View` right?

Comment: Yes. It's an ImageView

Comment: Okay see my answer, it's tested on a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that, after the first 
you call `fruit[0].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`:

```
fruit[0].postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        fruit[0].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }, getRandomDisplayTime());
```

and:

```
fruit[0].postDelayed(this, getRandomWaitTime());
```

are executed almost at the same time (immediately).

So, let's say for example the `getRandomDisplayTime()` return 3000 and `getRandomWaitTime()` returns 3500, you will see the view visible after 3000 milliseconds and after 500 milliseconds more, it will disappear again.

You can change your code in this way:

```
fruit[0].postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Runnable runnable = this;
                fruit[0].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fruit[0].postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        fruit[0].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        fruit[0].postDelayed(runnable, getRandomWaitTime());
                    }
                }, getRandomDisplayTime());
            }
        }, getRandomWaitTime());
```

Comment: Used recursion and now everything works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a bit messy, try this example. Based on the view itself, values will be chosen instead of nested `postDelayed()` methods.

```
fruit[0].postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        fruit[0].setVisibility(backButton.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
        fruit[0].postDelayed(this, backButton.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? getRandomDisplayTime() : getRandomWaitTime());
    }
}, fruit[0].getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? getRandomDisplayTime() : getRandomWaitTime());
```